# If an ODE depends on $f \in C^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R})$ but not on $f'$, does the same hold for its solution?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider an ordinary differential equation (ODE)

$$F(t, y, y') =0$$

in the unknown $y \in C^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R})$. Suppose that $F$ depends on a smooth function $f \in C^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R})$, yet there is no explicit dependence on $f'$ or higher order derivatives.

For example, one such differential equation is

$$y' + \tan(f)y = 0.$$

Under such assumptions, I would like to ask the following question.

**Question.** Suppose that the general solution of the ODE exists for all $f \in C^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R})$. Can we then conclude that, *as a function of $f$*, the solution does not depend explicitly on $f'$ or higher order derivatives?

In general, one cannot hope to find an explicit formula for the solution as a function of $f$. So I wonder whether it really makes sense to speak of "explicit dependence".

Comment: A more precise question would be whether $y$ depends continuously on $f$ for $f$ in $L^\infty$, as opposed to a space involving derivatives such as $C^1$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for the feedback! I have edited the question, hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: You did not clarify the main point. What does "depend explicitly " mean? Nothing. The way your question is, the existing answer still applies.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see it now. Without an explicit formula for the solution in terms of , which is not available, speaking of "explicit dependence on $f'$" makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

In general: The solution may depend on $f'$ (although it's kind of an exploit used here).

An Example: Consider $$y' + fy = 0$$ for $$f(x) = \sin(x)$$ with suitable initial conditions.
Then as a solution we get $$y(x) = e^{\cos(x)} = e^{f'(x)}$$

So the solution depends on $f'$.

Comment: +1. The question is not precise enough so it allows for answer like this one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I meant to ask something different, please see my edit. Sorry that I was not able to explain the question well enough.